# Wait for the nextTick before asserting with vitest

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, vitest

I have a composable exporting a reactive primitive `foo` and a function `onFooChange`. Inside this composable lies a watcher watching `foo` and on change it will call `onFooChange`.

I need to write a unit test to check if the watcher is executed. To do so I am trying to spy on `onFooChange` to see if it has been called after I change `foo`.

My unit test looks like this :

```
  test("check if foo() was called", async () => {
    const fooComposable = useFoo();
    const spy = vi.spyOn(fooComposable, "onFooChange");

    // changing foo to trigger the watcher
    fooComposable.foo = "newData";

    // TODO Wait for the next tick before asserting
    // ???

    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledOnce();
  });
```

This test obviously fail due to the fact that the assertion happens before the watcher triggers. How can I wait for the nextTick to be able to spy on the call ?

---

More information :

Wrapping the asserion in a setTimeout 0 like this :

```
setTimeout(() => {
  expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledOnce();
}, 0);
```

works since `setTimeout` addes the assertion at the end of the event loop tasks queue so the assertion runs after the nextTick but I need a more elegent and vue/vitest friendly solution.

I found `vi.runAllTicks` in [Vitest doc](https://vitest.dev/api/vi.html#vi-runallticks) but as you can see the doc is brief

Answer (score 1):

I think you can simply await it. Just tested this and it worked perfectly

```
import { test, expect, vi } from 'vitest'
import { ref, watch, nextTick } from 'vue'

test('foo', async () => {
  const foo = ref(111)
  const spy = vi.fn()
  watch(foo, spy)

  foo.value = 222
  await nextTick()
  expect(spy).toBeCalledTimes(1)
})
```

Comment: I can't make it work. Can you  the composable you used for your test ?

Comment: I updated the answer with a simpler example

Comment: thanks, I ll try to make it work with spyOn and a composable to match my case